# Search only particular folder in Directory

Tags: c#

I need to search particular folder in directory.

I dont want to go for files, no need to search files.

I can search particular folder in directory but for I have to go for loop of files like

```
foreach (FileInfo f in dir.EnumerateFiles())
{
      //code
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.EnumerateDirectories())
{
   Call function recursively
}
```

I need to search particular folder only. Because I have so many files around 20,000 , so If I use above code than loop will go all the files, and take more time.

But I need some folders only like

```
Regex.IsMatch(dir.FullName, @"1293.*T.*"))
```

How can i do that without going in files loop.

Comment: Im not sure what your wanting, but by the sounds of it, you will only need to run the `foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.EnumerateDirectories())
{
   Call function recursively
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the search pattern provided by the overload of `Directory.GetDirectory` isn't strong enough for your needs, you can use a custom method.

```
static string SearchDirectory(string path, string pattern)
{
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    foreach (var d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        var dirName = d.Substring(d.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        if (regex.IsMatch(dirName)) return d;
        SearchDirectory(d, pattern);
    }
    return null;
    //Or throw an Exception
}
```

You might want to surround the `foreach` loop in a `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) that accepts a search pattern.

For example:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\", "c*");
```

Comment: I have used dir.EnumerateDirectories("1293*T*") ... its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing, but do you want to get the directories that match the Regex pattern?

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.EnumerateDirectories().Where(d => Regex.IsMatch(dir.FullName, @"1293.*T.*")))
{

}
```